# Running out of memory for no reason?

Tags: android-studio

I'm extremely new to android studio so sorry if this question is really simple.

I'm basically trying to have 2 screens:
Menu, and instructions.

The instructions is an intent to the menu screen (a button click will open the instructions from the menu)

Now, when I'm trying to put an image as the background for the instructions layout, it gives me an out of memory error.

However, if I put the same BG image as I have in the menu layout into the instructions layout, it will work, and the ironic part is that the BG image for the menu layout is **bigger** than the BG im trying to put in the instructions layout.

Worth mentioning these are images from the drawables menu, Menu BG: 31k, Instructions BG(the one that crashes): 30k, both are made by me in photoshop, same save settings, same image type, everything.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post your build.gradle file and are you using any image compression library? have you included google play services in your app?

Comment: How do I find my build.gradle file in order to post it? and I am not using and libraries / google play services.

Answer (score 0):

in reference to the comment above ---> you can find your gradle.build file inside the tree view on the left side of your project file structure view.
or from your computers GUI 
inside

android_studio_projects/"your_app_name"/app/build.gradle

And I am almost positive that the reason you are getting this error is because the images should be in the mipmap folder and properly seperated in the sizing folders from mipmap ldpi to mipmap xxxhdpi.

ldpi (low) ~120dpi
mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
hdpi (high) ~240dpi
xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

If the device/emulator you are using attempts to over expand an image (kinda like overcompensating because it thinks the image is two small because it is unclassified and inside the drawable folder.

A good way to test it is to put your image inside the mipmap xxxhdpi folder. If your app runs instead of crashing then congrats you fixed it.

(In order to add a file into a specific mipmap simply paste it into the mipmap folder by left clicking it and selecting paste. and android studios will automatically ask you what density specific folder you would like it in.)

Hope this helps best of luck.